# SwipeRefreshLayout with RecyclerView not working in Fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask, swiperefreshlayout

I have a recyclerview inside SwipeRefreshLayout in a fragment. I have implemented AsyncTask to fetch data for recyclerview. The problem is SwipeRefreshLayout does not show at all, and hence the data is not populated in recyclerview. I have done the same thing for Activity and it works just fine but not in fragment. Can  anybody guide me what am I doing wrong?
This is the layout file for fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".FeatureFragment">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is what I've done in the fragment class.

```
public class FeaturedFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeLayout;
    public FeaturedFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_featured_captions, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mSwipeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.refresh_layout);
        mSwipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        new FetchFeedTask().execute((Void) null);
    }


    private class FetchFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mSwipeLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //things to do in background
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
            mSwipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(/*adapter*/);
            //things to do at the end
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Add `SwipeRefreshLayout` as root layout.

Comment: @MehulSolanki I don't want to because I have some views to add above SwipeRefreshLayout

Comment: you can not have things above the swipe to refresh layout, it needs to be the root. you can have "things" above the recycler view, but not above the swiperefresh

Comment: @JoachimHaglund that's probably not true. I have tested it and you can have views above SwipeRefreshLayout.

Comment: Can you try to add `android:clickable="true"` inside your `LinearLayout`. that may help

Comment: @MehulSolanki no, that does not help.

Comment: @DineshNeupane any solution ?

Comment: @SagarMaiyad Nope. I ended up making a custom loading view

Comment: @DineshNeupane can i know how you did that?

Comment: @SagarMaiyad setup a loading view and recyclerview, set it's visibility as GONE when data is loaded.

Answer (score 7):

It's too late to answer here but might help someone else.
I faced the same issue and it is because the recyclerView is immediate child of swipeRefreshLayout  so simply put the recyclerView in a layout (for example ConstraintLayout) and then put this layout in your swipeRefreshLayout and everything will work as you expected.

Comment: I confirm this worked for me!

Comment: i confirm this work for me too. it's kinda weird though cause i have exactly the same layout where recyclerView is immediate child of swipeRefreshLayout and it's works fine but other layout need this adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

> Change the height of `swipelayout` to `wrap_content`

**Solution 1** :)

```
 <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

**Solution 2**:) Use swipe layout and recycler view using design library

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
         <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: I've tried the first solution already, no luck. For second, since I've already moved to androidx I can't use support libraries.

Answer (score 0):

May your code not working because of `ReacyclerView` scroll `Listener` 
Try below snipped.

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        int topRowVerticalPosition =
                (recyclerView == null || recyclerView.getChildCount() == 0) ? 0 : recyclerView.getChildAt(0).getTop();
        mSwipeLayout.setEnabled(topRowVerticalPosition >= 0);

    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }
});
```

Also, add your initialization stuff inside `onViewCreated()` like below

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_featured_captions, container, false);
        return view;
    }



    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mSwipeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.refresh_layout);
        mSwipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **NestedScrollView** . put your recycleview or listview inside it. with

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

Complete example -

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.customfont.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Title"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <com.customfont.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/title2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Title"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/mSwipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">


      <com.pagenia.app.exoplayer.utils.ExoPlayerRecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/exoPlayerRecyclerView"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
          android:background="#FFFFFF"
          android:dividerHeight="8dp" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score -3):

Try using the below snippet:

Always use support library widgets. instead of these:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

and

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
```

So:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: support library is depreciated, androidX is the new way to do things and functionally, it's no different.